# I need to add a DataGridView to the form dynamically

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void btnShowCausali_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    DataGridView Dati = new DataGridView();
    Dati.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
    Dati.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(120, 40);
    Dati.Name = "Dati";
    Dati.RowTemplate.Height = 24;
    Dati.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(979, 458);
    Dati.TabIndex = 1;
    Dati.Visible = true;
    Dati.Columns.Add("id", "ID");
    Dati.Columns.Add("causaliname", "Nome Causale");
    Dati.Columns.Add("Identificationcode", "Codice Identificativo");
    Dati.Columns.Add("expired", "Data di Scadenza");
    grpDatore.Controls.Add(Dati);      
}
```

When I run this code the DataGridView does not appear on the form. Just in case it could create problem, the button `btnShowCausali` get created on the form load.

```
public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btnShowCausali = new Button();
    btnShowCausali.Text = "Causali";
    btnShowCausali.Location = new Point(20, 20);
    btnShowCausali.Size = new Size(120, 40);
}
```

By the way, I don't know why the button actually gets created but the DataGridView does not.

Comment: What is `grpDatore` you should add to `Form` like `this.Controls.Add(Dati)`

Comment: Are you sure that `btnShowCausali` is created? Because you haven't added it to your form!

Comment: Use visual designer of VS. Why you do this manually?

Comment: And you haven't assigned the button its handler

Comment: Also you have not bind `Click Event Handler` to the `Button` you have created

Comment: @i486 There is several reasons that someone need to add controls to the form dynamically.

Comment: so how do i bind the eventhandler to the button?

Comment: @S.Akbari I know this, but he can use VS designer to see what it generates and compare with his code. OK?

Comment: @LorenzoValenti Like this `btnShowCausali.Click += BtnShowCausali_Click;`

Comment: double click your button from the UI and move this code to that event

Comment: the button is also created dinamically, so i don't have it on the UI

Comment: Could you explain why you need to create those UI controls dynamically? (you know you could design your form with the designer and hide/show controls dynamically? for example if you want to ONLY show the DataGridView AFTER the button was clicked make it hidden to begin with and change its visibility at button click)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your event handler btnShowCausali_Click is not attached to the button in Form1_Load. Are you sure it is called?
I also do not see adding this button to any container (Form, Panel, ...)
Your DataGridView will be added to grpDatore control (not form) so have that in mind when you set Location.

Attach event:

```
btnShowCausali.Click += btnShowCausali_Click;
```

Comment: how do i call it

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if the button is created dynamically, add it to the UI.

```
Button btnShowCausali = new Button();
btnShowCausali.Text = "Causali";
btnShowCausali.Location = new Point(20, 20); // Make shure there aren't other controls in this point
btnShowCausali.Size = new Size(120, 40);
this.Controls.Add(btnShowCausali); //Adding the button to the form
```

Then, you have to attach an event handler for the `Click` event of the button. In short, you have to tell to the button what to do when it is clicked. You have two options to add an event handler for the click event:

1. Code: add `btnShowCausali.Click += btnShowCausali_Click;` after the `InitializeComponent` function call (in the constructor) or in the `Load` event of the form. Then add the function `btnShowCausali_Click`:

   ```
   private void btnShowCausali_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        DataGridView Dati = new DataGridView();
       Dati.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
       Dati.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(120, 40);
       Dati.Name = "Dati";
       Dati.RowTemplate.Height = 24;
       Dati.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(979, 458);
       Dati.TabIndex = 1;
       Dati.Visible = true;
       Dati.Columns.Add("id", "ID");
       Dati.Columns.Add("causaliname", "Nome Causale");
       Dati.Columns.Add("Identificationcode", "Codice Identificativo");
       Dati.Columns.Add("expired", "Data di Scadenza");
       grpDatore.Controls.Add(Dati); // DataGridView added to grpDatore, not form. Make shure grpDatore is visible.
   }
   ```
2. Designer: double click on the button. Visual Studio will do the magic for you.